# Is it possible to list all third-level domains of the given second-level domain?

Tags: dns, dig

For example, suppose I want to list all third-level domains of google.com. That list should look like

```
 translate.google.com
 plus.google.com
```

etc. Is it possible to get that list for an arbitrary second-level domain?

Comment: There are a variety of tool which list subdomains, like https://www.nmmapper.com/sys/tools/subdomainfinder/ - but they cannot guarantee that they know about *all* subdomains. And if a domain is used for DNS Tunneling, the list of subdomains may be "all possible subdomain names for that domain".

Answer (score 1):

In practice, no.

It may be possible for a specific domain, if the owner of the domain felt like it. Find the name servers for the domain in question (`dig ns google.com`), then ask one of them for a zone transfer (`dig axfr google.com @ns1.google.com`) and see if you get a list of names or a short error message.